# how to display realtime window content while Sliding window on the entire image in python code

Tags: python, image-processing, sliding-window

I'm going to scan an entire image with a window by specific size and  do an analysis on each patch.while swiping window I'm going to show real-time scanning process but with my code attached below it stops and need to close the image manually then it shows the next shifted patch. Can any anyone help me how can turn this manually displaying to like online process in a one window display automatically.

```
from skimage import io,morphology
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Window= 65
W=np.round(Window/2)
image = io.imread('My Image Address')
Ishape=np.shape(image)
stepSize= 20
windowSize= 50
WS=25

for Ci in range((1+WS),(Ishape[0]-(WS+1)),stepSize):
    for Cj in range((1+WS),(Ishape[1]-(WS+1)),stepSize):
             patch = image[(Ci - WS):(Ci + WS), (Cj - WS):(Cj + WS), :]
             im = Image.fromarray(patch,'RGB')
             plt.imshow(im)
             plt.show()
```